# Qtile3 plugin not found!

Tags: qgis-plugins

I installed version 3.4.0 and repeatedly searched for the QTILE3(QTiles and QTile , i try both of them) plugin, but failed. Why do not I find this plugin?can anyone help me?

[image]
[image]

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles/issues/94 you can use Tiles XYZ I think

Comment: I've reviewed this page over and over again. Sorry, this plugin was not found.
You do not have a solution???

Comment: Edit your question to show us also a screengrab of your settings page.

Comment: Are you looking for "QTILE3" or "QTILES3"? Because I can't find "QTILE3" but I can find "QTILES3". All your screenshots show "QTILE3".

Comment: I can not find this plugin at all. I searched again. This time I typed the word QTiles3 but nothing was found. @Spacedman

Answer (score 3):

The developers, NextGIS, have not ported this plugin to QGIS3 for their own reasons, and Lutra posted the QTILES3 plugin. Due to copyright issues, this plugin was removed in favor of a more thought out solution. QGIS 3.8 (3.7 Dev) should be able to read/write mbtiles natively through the development of Lutra. [See documentation here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/9857)

Comment: I entered the downloaded tiles using xyz tiles, now I want to select a specific area and get the MBtile output. How do I do this? In the Save as menu, how do I add the Column and Row numbers? How many zoom sizes?  @HDunn

Answer (score 1):

QTiles3 is "Experimental"...

[image]

Have you enabled Experimental plugins in the settings?

[image]

Comment: I've reviewed this page over and over again. Sorry, this plugin was not found.
You do not have a solution?????

Comment: Cant tell without seeing your settings. All I know is that if I don't have this box ticked I get your problem, if I do tick this box then I can get the plugin. But it could be some other settings problem, like maybe the repo isn't in the list of repositories. Please edit your Q and show a screenshot of the settings page.

Comment: I do tick this box then I can not get the plugin.why? I installed version 3.4.8 and repeatedly searched for the QTILE3 plugin, but failed